# Xcode 4.6 and iOS 7.0.2 connecting issue?

Tags: xcode, ios7

When I am connecting my iPAD with iOS 7.0.2 with Xcode 4.6. It is showing iOS device not my device name.Is there an issue between Xcode 4.6 and iOS 7.0.2?

Comment: use xcode5 with ios 7+

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you are using devices with iOS 7, you should be using Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

The latest iOS version will always be compatible with the recent most SDK available i.e. Xcode 5.0.2 in your case for iOS7.